# Access to JSON values of array (Flowable )

Tags: flowable

Im creating a flow that calls a web servcice and then it reads and show the values. But can't view values of result.myArray[0].SECCION. When I look in debug mode it has values but flowable cant show them

[Screenshot 1: Only view json obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QetmP.png)

[Screenshot 2:looking at my value of 0 position called SECCION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyOEd.png)

The JSON values result of calling web service:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/47zzGQ7m

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way : 
${ resultado.rows.elements().next().SECCION }

Answer (score 0):

`result.myArray.required(0).SECCION` will work as

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 6.5.0 it is now possible to use `[]`.

So `result.myArray[0].SECCION` should work from 6.5.0.